# base64binary is referenced but not defined

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I'm trying to generate a webservice client with eclipse ganymede, using this wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="ArrayRadicar">
  <xsd:all>
   <xsd:element name="numero_radicado" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="error" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:all>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="radicarDocumentoPRequest">
  <part name="file" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="fileName" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="login" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="cc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="destinatarioOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="predioOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="espOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="asu" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="med" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="ane" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="coddepe" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tpRadicado" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="cuentai" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="radi_usua_actu" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="numeroFolios" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tdoc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tip_doc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="carp_codi" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="carp_per" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="radicarDocumentoPResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="radicarDocumentoP2Request">
  <part name="file" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="fileName" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="file2" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="fileName2" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="file3" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="fileName3" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="login" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="cc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="destinatarioOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="predioOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="espOrg" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="asu" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="med" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="ane" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="coddepe" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tpRadicado" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="cuentai" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="radi_usua_actu" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="numeroFolios" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tdoc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="tip_doc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="carp_codi" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="carp_per" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="radicarDocumentoP2Response">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="crearAnexoRequest">
  <part name="radiNume" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="file" type="xsd:base64binary" />
  <part name="filename" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="descripcion" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaDoc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaLogin" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="crearAnexoResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="cambiarImagenRadRequest">
  <part name="numRadicado" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="ext" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="file" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="cambiarImagenRadResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="consultaRadicadoRequest">
  <part name="numRadicado" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="consultaRadicadoResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="consultaRadicado2Request">
  <part name="numRadicado" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codVer" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="consultaRadicado2Response">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="crearUsuarioRequest">
  <part name="usuaLogin" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaDoc" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codigoDependencia" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaRol" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaNombre" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="usuaEmail" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="crearUsuarioResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<portType name="Servicio Web OrfeoPortType">
  <operation name="radicarDocumentoP">
    <documentation>Radicacion de un documento en Orfeo</documentation>
    <input message="tns:radicarDocumentoPRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:radicarDocumentoPResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="radicarDocumentoP2">
    <documentation>Radicacion de un documento en Orfeo con anexos</documentation>
    <input message="tns:radicarDocumentoP2Request"/>
    <output message="tns:radicarDocumentoP2Response"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="crearAnexo">
    <documentation>Metodo que permite anexar archivos anexos a un radicado especifico .</documentation>
    <input message="tns:crearAnexoRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:crearAnexoResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="cambiarImagenRad">
    <documentation>Cambiar imagen a un radicado</documentation>
    <input message="tns:cambiarImagenRadRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:cambiarImagenRadResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="consultaRadicado">
    <documentation>Consultar Datos de un Radicado</documentation>
    <input message="tns:consultaRadicadoRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:consultaRadicadoResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="consultaRadicado2">
    <documentation>Consultar Datos de un Radicado Completo</documentation>
    <input message="tns:consultaRadicado2Request"/>
    <output message="tns:consultaRadicado2Response"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="crearUsuario">
    <documentation>Creacion de Un Usuario en Orfeo</documentation>
    <input message="tns:crearUsuarioRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:crearUsuarioResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Servicio Web OrfeoBinding" type="tns:Servicio Web OrfeoPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="radicarDocumentoP">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor#radicarDocumentoP" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="radicarDocumentoP2">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor#radicarDocumentoP2" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.proovedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="crearAnexo">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo#crearAnexo" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="cambiarImagenRad">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo#cambiarImagenRad" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="consultaRadicado">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor#consultaRadicado" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="consultaRadicado2">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor#consultaRadicado2" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:co.fna.orfeo.prooveedor" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="crearUsuario">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo#crearUsuario" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:org.FNA.webserviceorfeo" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Servicio Web Orfeo">
  <port name="Servicio Web OrfeoPort" binding="tns:Servicio Web OrfeoBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://172.16.125.68/webServices/servidorOrfeo.php"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

and I getting this error:

```
IWAB0399E Error al generar Java a partir de WSDL:  java.io.IOException: Type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}base64binary is referenced but not defined.
```

I'm using Apache Axis 1.4, java 1.6, this wsdl was generated with php nusoap.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The datatype base64binary is wrong spelled, It must be base64**B**inary (with B uppercase). NuSoap generate the wsdl in a wrong way.

Thanks.